# How to create a geometry for each feature in a stringified geometry collection from a BigQuery JavaScript UDF?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm new to UDF functions and I have created a BigQuery UDF that takes a polygon geometry and creates points with it. I'm trying to draw dot density maps (converting polygon + population number to points). I've adapted the code from [this blog post](https://observablehq.com/@aboutaaron/racial-demographic-dot-density-map). Because bigQuery doesn't have a way to log variables, I've been testing things out [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/kpennell/pen/WNxwzxo?editors=0010).

I'm at a point where the function seems to work right. The output is a geometry collection of points. It says in the bigquery docs that `st_geogfromgeojson` can accept a geometry collection.

My UDF returns a stringified geometry collection.

But I cannot figure out why `st_geogfromgeojson` doesn't work. I can't tell if I'm simply not unnesting something or what.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(feature string, ethnicity_column FLOAT64, year INT64)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE js
  OPTIONS (
    library=["https://storage.googleapis.com.../d3.js","https://storage.googleapis.com/.../turf.min.js","https://storage.googleapis.com/.../wellknown.js"]
  )
  AS
    """
          
        if (feature === undefined || feature === null) return;
       
        
        var feature_parsed = wellknown.parse(feature)
       
        const bounds = turf.bbox(feature_parsed);
        
        const populationData = Math.round(ethnicity_column / 10);
        if (!populationData) return;
       
         const x_min = bounds[0];
         const y_min = bounds[1];
         const x_max = bounds[2];
         const y_max = bounds[3];
  
        let hits = 0;
        let count = 0;
        const limit = populationData * 10; // limit test to 10x the population.
        let points = [];
        while (hits < populationData - 1 && count < limit) {
          const lat = y_min + Math.random() * (y_max - y_min);
          const lng = x_min + Math.random() * (x_max - x_min);
          const randomPoint = turf.point([lng, lat]);
          if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(randomPoint, feature_parsed)) {
            points.push(randomPoint);
            hits++;
          }
          count++;
        }
        return JSON.stringify((turf.geometryCollection(points)));
        
       // return JSON.stringify(points)

    """;


SELECT ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON(JSON_EXTRACT((myFunc(st_astext(geom), white_pop, 2018)),'$')) FROM `myteam.kyle_data.blockgroups_with_acs`
```

But I keep hitting random errors like I'm not using the function right  [image]

I'm open to all suggestions. I return a string for simplicity but perhaps I need to use a STRUCT. Perhaps I should cut out turf from creating the points? I must be missing something here.

Comment: Can you post output of 
SELECT (myFunc(st_astext(geom), white_pop, 2018)) FROM `myteam.kyle_data.blockgroups_with_acs` ?

Comment: Sure thing: 
```{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.54238874622482,48.90183791377525]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.53394002893639,48.869685080847184]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":```

Comment: that's a bit bizarre. At the top you have Feature with GeometryCollection, that's good. But  that GeometryCollection's geometries field contains Features, where it should contain geometries according to GeoJson RFC. I think BigQuery errors comes from that nested Feature inside GeometryCollection.

Comment: @MichaelEntin Yeah, I'm very confused. I've learned a ton about bigQuery udfs through doing this but yeah...not sure what to try. Could I simply avoid all this and just return the points array like shown? https://codepen.io/kpennell/pen/WNxwzxo?editors=0010

Then just parse the geometry out of the feature?

Seems like turf is doing something wrong here. Maybe I should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that fixed it:

- Returning `array<String>` instead of string
- CROSS JOIN UNNEST in the `select`

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myFunc(feature string, ethnicity_column FLOAT64)
  RETURNS array<String>
  LANGUAGE js
  OPTIONS (
    library=["https://storage.googleapis.com/../d3.js","https://storage.googleapis.com/.../turf.min.js","https://storage.googleapis.com/.../wellknown.js"]
  )
  AS
    """
        geopath = d3.geoPath()
        if (feature === undefined || feature === null) return;
        var feature_parsed = wellknown.parse(feature)
        const bounds = turf.bbox(feature_parsed);
        const populationData = Math.round(ethnicity_column / 10);
        if (!populationData) return;
         const x_min = bounds[0];
         const y_min = bounds[1];
         const x_max = bounds[2];
         const y_max = bounds[3];
        let hits = 0;
        let count = 0;
        const limit = populationData; // limit test to 10x the population.
        let points = [];
        while (hits < populationData - 1 && count < limit) {
          const lat = y_min + Math.random() * (y_max - y_min);
          const lng = x_min + Math.random() * (x_max - x_min);
          const randomPoint = turf.point([lng, lat]);
          if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(randomPoint, feature_parsed)) {
            points.push('POINT ('+lng+' '+lat+')');
            hits++;
          }
          count++;
        }
        return points;
    """;
SELECT st_geogfromtext(points) as the_geom,  'white' as ethnicity  from (SELECT (myFunc(st_astext(geom), white_pop)) as points FROM `tableonmybq`) CROSS JOIN UNNEST(points) as points
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoJson has two different collection types:

- one is `GeometryCollection` - which is a geometry that describes a collection of geometries, e.g. union of points and polygons would be a GeometryCollection.
- another is `FeatureCollection` - collection of features, objects with various properties, including `geometry` (which could be a geometry collection or any other geometry) and other user-defined properties.

turf.geometryCollection seems to return a `Feature`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-geometrycollection (this is why it also accepts `properties` parameter).

`ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON` constructs a geometry, it does support `GeometryCollection`, but does not support `FeatureCollection` or singular `Feature` returned by turf.

What you can do is extract a `geometry` from this feature,  and pass it to `ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON`. I think just using JSON selector `$.geometry` instead of `$` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The core issue seems to be that turf says it returning a GeometryCollection when it's really a FeatureCollection. 



`ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON(JSON_EXTRACT((myFunc(st_astext(geom), white_pop, 2018)),'$.geometry'))`

Still gets `ST_GeogFromGeoJSON failed: GeoJSON reader accepts Geometry objects, not Feature or FeatureCollection objects`

So it sounds like I need to either debug turf or figure out how to get the geometries out of this de facto featurecollection

Comment: From the description, I would expect turf to return a Feature, not FeatureCollection. Feature usually looks like { type: feature, geometry: { ... }, properties { } }, where the content of geometry property is GeoJson (in GeometryCollection in this case).

Comment: Still stuck on this but your suggestions were helpful @MichaelEntin